# Use data-id for wordpress posts (individually)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

I get the filters script implemented on my wordpress web by some developer, who's not good in wordpress functions but he did implement the filter script on web.
That script is working on projects page, where it displayed the custom portfolio items (or custom posts).
These portfolio items on projects page are in list format (li) and when i add the new post/portfolio from the backend, it displayed on that projects page and automatically assigned the li class "grid-item" , that class is assigned by the template which i am using, name is kallium  http://demo.kaliumtheme.com/architecture/our-work/
To make this filter system work, i have to include the filter class in my posts(portfolio items) so i actually want to assign the different classes in different posts manually. It could be done by data-id attribute but i am not sure how to use this attribute in posts, so it will override the class, which is automatically assigned to portfolio items by theme script. 
Another way is to, disable/remove the theme script which automatically assigned the default class "grid-item" to grid items (li) but i am not good in javascript, so i can't find the right script to disable.
Here's the project page http://goo.gl/YczBzP
Filter script is included as filter.js 
I need the help to make this filter work for my portfolio items, manual way or js

Comment: your site uses IsotopeJS, the grid-item class seems to be generated by PHP during foreach or wordpress loop, filter.js is a configuration of isotope and some additional jquery functionality like adding some custom class like comercial, residencial, cultural, active, etc. additionally, its not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: If you check in projects page, there's some items with the li class="grid-item-residencial, culutral or others. I want to use these filter classes (from filter.js) for posts , instead of grid-item.

Comment: What could be the auto or manual way to use the custom classes (like comercial, residencial, cultural, active) in posts/portfolio items?

Comment: just remove the code that ad those class in filter.js and add the class in php loop or create a metabox to assign custom class and include it on the custom loop

Comment: I am not good in php or wordpress functions, have a little knowledge with metaboxes but still i need the coding help to place in projects page. Custom php loop, may be. I actually want to filter the categories in wordpress so it displays the items of category in project page.

Comment: I put the project code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093099/isotope-filtering-with-wordpress-by-categories<br>. check if you can help me with codes.