# Call/link wordpress category with jquery/isotope classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am working on the portfolio section of my web, and these codes i have in filter.js script (in wp-includes/js folder)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".grid-item").first().addClass("comercial");
    jQuery(".grid-item:eq(1)").addClass("residencial");
    jQuery(".grid-item:eq(2)").addClass("cultural");
    jQuery(".grid-item:eq(3)").addClass("interiores");
    jQuery(".grid-item:eq(4)").addClass("residencial");
            jQuery(".grid-item:eq(5)").addClass("residencial");
    jQuery('.grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });

    jQuery(".dcjq-parent-li ul li a").click(function() {
        jQuery(".dcjq-parent-li ul li a").removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        var filtro=jQuery(this).attr("data-filter");
        jQuery(".grid").isotope({ filter: filtro});
    });

    jQuery(".dcjq-parent").click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).siblings("ul").css("display")=="block")
            jQuery(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle( "slow" );
        else
        {
            jQuery(".accordionMenu ul").each(function( index ) {
                if(jQuery(this).css('display')=="block")
                {
                    jQuery(this).slideToggle( "slow" );
                    jQuery(this).siblings("a").removeClass("active");
                }
            });
            jQuery(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle( "slow" );
            jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });

});
```

I have the different classes in above codes, but i am not sure how to use these classes in wordpress posts or how to create a function/loop to use these classes in posts.

That code i have in my portfolio page:

```
<div id="aside">
    <ul id="subMenu" class="accordionMenu" data-option-key="filter">                        
        <li class="dcjq-parent-li">
            <a href="#" class="dcjq-parent active">Tipologia<span class="dcjq-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <ul style="display: block;">
                <li><a href="#filter" data-filter="*" class="active">todos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".residencial">Residencial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".comercial">Comercial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".cultural">Cultural</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".interiores">Interiores</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dcjq-parent-li">
            <a href="#" class="dcjq-parent">Datas<span class="dcjq-icon"></span></a>
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#filter" data-filter="*" class="actv">todos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".1980, .1981, .1982, .1983, .1984">1980 - 1984</a></li><li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".1985, .1986, .1987, .1988, .1989">1985 - 1989</a></li><li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".1990, .1991, .1992, .1993, .1994">1990 - 1994</a></li><li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".1995, .1996, .1997, .1998, .1999">1995 - 1999</a></li><li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".2000, .2001, .2002, .2003, .2004">2000 - 2004</a></li><li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".2005, .2006, .2007, .2008, .2009">2005 - 2009</a></li><li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".2010, .2011, .2012, .2013, .2014">2010 - 2014</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>                                   
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="projecto"><div class="grid">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=-1');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>

<?php if($feat_image!=''){?>    <li class="grid-item"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="proimg"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $feat_image;?>" /></div></a>
<h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                       <div class="textblock"><?php echo $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'text', true ); ?>
</div>
                       </li><?php } ?>
<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar( $blog-widgets ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have done all these codes by reading the tutorials of wordpress/isotope integration, create the classes in jquery, do codes on project page and what i didn't understand is how to use these isotope/jquery classes in wordpress posts
so they will be appear as filters.
I know, it could be done via category filtering, tags, metabox or custom loop but i don't know how exactly to create the custom loop, which use the filter classes in categories.
Sorry, if i didn't ask the question in right way, i am a beginner and trying to do everything by tutorials and by the help of experts.

Comment: post your code that generates the HTML element

Comment: Which codes? Filters are working by isotope script http://goo.gl/s0K0eJ, project page and filter code is above, so for which html element i have to provide the codes, please explain a bit and i will post the codes here.

Comment: I posted the complete codes of project page, which generates the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove JS code that automatically add the class that you wanted to be added manually,

these lines

```
jQuery(".grid-item").first().addClass("comercial");
jQuery(".grid-item:eq(1)").addClass("residencial");
jQuery(".grid-item:eq(2)").addClass("cultural");
jQuery(".grid-item:eq(3)").addClass("interiores");
jQuery(".grid-item:eq(4)").addClass("residencial");
jQuery(".grid-item:eq(5)").addClass("residencial");
```

in your wordpress loop, get the list of categories of the current item and store them in variable separated by space as this will be use as classes later,  you can use [get_the_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) function

```
//get the category assign to the post
//$cat_objects = get_the_category();
$cat_objects = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category');



/**Define category variable to be use as class, leave empty if you don't want to add global classes you can add 'grid-item' in here and remove it on the LI element, **/
$categories = '';

// Loop through each category object
foreach ( $cat_objects as $cat ) {

    // extract the category slug and add them to $categories variable, 
    $categories .=  ' '. $cat->slug; /** Added Space at the beginning of each category so they will be separated during actual output**/
}
```

you can then add the list of categories stored in the `$categories` variable from the code above as additional class for grid-item li's, `<li class="grid-item<?php echo $categories; ?>">`

Your loop should look something like this

```
<div class="projecto"><div class="grid">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=-1');
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

    $cat_objects = get_the_category();
    $categories = '';
    foreach ( $cat_objects as $cat ) {
        $categories .=  ' '. $cat->slug;
    }

    ?>
<?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>

<?php if($feat_image!=''){?>  <li class="grid-item<?php echo $categories; ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="proimg"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $feat_image;?>" /></div></a>
<h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                       <div class="textblock"><?php echo $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'text', true ); ?>
</div>
                       </li><?php } ?>
<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How to store the categories in variable, i did the following in loop:
$cat_objects = get_the_category();
    $categories = 'comercial, datas';
    foreach ( $cat_objects as $cat ) {
        $categories .=  'comercial, datas'. $cat->slug;
    }

Comment: Rest of the part is very easy, thanks for define it in easiest way.

Comment: I edited my Answer above and provide some additional explanation ```get_the_category``` is a function that pulls that item category as object, you don't need to add the categories manually on the php code, just a assign a category when you create a post (or whatever post type you are using) and the category slug will be automatically added as a class on HTML outpu. you don't need to modify the code above

Comment: Man, i did exactly as above but still it's not working. On the back end i have separate categories option for portfolio post types. So it should be <?php echo $portfolio-categories; ?> , right?

Comment: I find this with inspection tool (portfolio categories, it's in same tab with portfolio items) from wordpress "<a href="edit-tags.php?taxonomy=portfolio_category&amp;post_type=portfolio">Portfolio Categories</a>"

Comment: Edited the code, [get_the_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions//) is for pulling wordpress built-in category, you need to use [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) if you are using custom taxonomy, you can't also echo an undefined variable which is ```$portfolio-categories;```

Comment: Thanks man, you helped a lot. But still it doesn't work, we are now calling the custom post categories, it should have worked. Can you please take a look here http://goo.gl/1Zyta4 , if we need to modify something here.
or here <li class="grid-item<?php echo $categories; ?>">
do i need to modify this?

Comment: On projects page, it didn't show anything upon click on filters.

Comment: you need to check if the HTML output are correct, if its configured properly, the li elements should be like ```<li class="grid-item category1 category2 categroy3...```

Comment: No, it's not displaying the categories, only grid-item like this <li class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><a href="http://pjvarquitetura.com.br/portfolio/casa-csp-penha-sc-2011-2014/"><div class="proimg"><img alt="" src="http://pjvarquitetura.com.br/wp-content/uploads/nova-casa-csp.jpg"></div></a>
<h5><a href="http://pjvarquitetura.com.br/portfolio/casa-csp-penha-sc-2011-2014/">Casa CSP – Penha SC</a></h5>
                       <div class="textblock">PENHA | 2011 - 2014</div>
                       </li>

Comment: you need to debug this ```$cat_objects = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category');```

Comment: Bro, it's working now. Appreciate your help and keep helping the beginners here, you are good in this. Thanks :)